# Will CSS rtl have any adverse language effects?

Tags: html, css, multilingual

I'm using the CSS direction property to set the horizontal visual order of `<div>` and `<figcaption>` tags, within a `<figure>` tag:

```
<figure>
    <div>
        <img src... />
    </div>
    <figcaption>Some text...</figcaption>
</figure>
```

In certain circumstances, I'd like the `<figcaption>` to appear before the `<div>` and its child `<img>`. In these cases, I'm using the following declaration:

```
figure {
    direction: rtl;
}
```

In all tested browsers this results in a perfectly legible `<figcaption>` that appears to the left of the `<img>`.

My question is, will this potentially have a negative effect on how the text is rendered in other browsers? I'm imagining the `<figcaption>` content potentially rendering in right-to-left. I know I *could* easily set the `<figcaption>` itself to ltr, but I wonder if this is strictly necessary.

Comment: Yes, this is a bad practice because the text rendering is fundamentally reversed, meaning that `hello.` will be `.hello` which I am sure you do not want. (and that's just one example) please use `text-align: right` or `float: right` instead, or Flexbox with reverse layout.

Comment: @Aziz Would the addition of `direction: ltr` on the figcaption be enough to mitigate? Floats are not an option, nor is flexbox sadly.